Submit Button says "Submit" on first page of multiple page form
Problem/Motivation
I have a multi-page form using Drupal 10. The pages are set up to use the wizard. There is one Submit button which is the default form actions button. I have set up what the Previous and Next button labels should say. These work once you are past the first page. However, on the first page of the form, the button says "Submit" not "Proceed".
If I click the "Test" tab, the button says "Proceed". The button that says "Submit" actually functions as a "Proceed" button. If I use this, then go backward, the button now says "Proceed". It only shows apparently when you first arrive at the form as an end user.
Steps to reproduce
Create a webform in Drupal 10.3.6. Install webform 6.2.7. Create several pages in the form. Set the form to use the wizard. Check the functionality of the actions button on the first page. For me, it says "Submit".
Perhaps I'm missing something, or this has come up before. I'm simply seeking support and not sure that it's actually a bug.

Strange! I switched themes from within the form itself. Now it shows "Proceed". I had previously switched themes globally but it didn't do anything. This tells me it might be a theme issue with the Bootstrap theme.

Hmm. I changed the theme from "Default" to my theme inside the form General settings and I think it's working now.

I forgot I changed the name of the label... to Proceed. When I reverted it back, changing the themes doesn't do anything. I think it's not theme-releated.
